# How to call, modify or update any parent element property when window.print() preview screen is in opened state

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ajax, typescript

I want to add new class to one of my parent DIV, if and only if window.print() preview window is opened. But the problem is that once window.print() opens the preview window, I can't change anything in the parent window. This is blocking any script for the parent window once the preview window is opened. I searched and read so many articles but I get only few options like "afterprint" or when we cancel the print window but my requirement is, I want to perform this action only when window is in open state.

I tried beforeprint as well, it fires before print window opens and I want to update the parent DIV class only when the print preview window is in open state

I tried in both chrome and firefox browsers.

Appreciate any suggestion on this.

Comment: Why don't you change it before opening and change it back after closing?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it is right what you say. But if you open the print dialog with the browser you need to detect it with the beforeprint event. I have posted a sample in my answer.

Comment: @Konrad I am using Angular and sending the HTML in DIV which is basically showing in print preview window. But the problem is the same DIV is displaying in the background in parent window when print preview window is opens. I want to hide the DIV when the print window opens but if hide the DIV, print window is also showing as blank so I just want to hide the DIV after loading the print preview window. I hope it clearly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9luixj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is a Stackblitz example. It works if you click the button to open the print dialog programmatically and it works if you open the dialog with the browser (menu/CMD + P), too.

You're on the right way. beforeprint is your friend. But it works in Angular only if you call detectChanges function.

```
constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

...

@HostListener('window:beforeprint', ['$event'])
  onBeforePrint(event: any) {
    this.newStyle = true;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();

    console.log('Before Print');
  }
```

Greetings, Flo

Comment: I tried but this is not working for me :(. I want to hide the same DIV in which the print content is showing after print preview load but if I update the class in beforeprint then even print preview will display blank. I have to update it after print view opens not before :(

Comment: So you can try ngx-print library. With it you can set a different html code to print as your view is.

Comment: Thanks for suggustion @flo but I can't use any library due to my app limitation :( . Any suggestion or solution without using new library?

Comment: You want to print a "other" view as the standard view (the view the user see)? So you can checkout the library i say and build your one. It's relatively easy to build your own print view and the only way is to set a custom print view to window.print()